# Oracle Maps filter.In allows me to only remove items from the map

Tags: oracle-spatial

Working from a basic example generated by Oracle MapBuilder. I have a base map and a FOI layer.

At the start no filter is applied and the map shows all object types (column OBJECTTYPE) available in the FOI layer.

```
 function addThemeBasedFOI()
  {
    layers["themebasedfoi1"] = layer1; 
    map.addLayer(layer1);
    layer1.setZoomLevelRange(0,9);
   }
```

A checkbox, initially unchecked, calls this function:

```
  function setFilter(item)
  {
    if (item.checked) {
      layer1.applyFilter(new OM.filter.In('OBJECTTYPE',["WGD","PND","OTD","BTD"]),true);
    }
    else
    {
    layer1.applyFilter(new OM.filter.In('OBJECTTYPE',["WGD","PND","OTD"]),true);

    }
  }
```

First click on the checkbox checks it and all objecttypes are removed from the layer except the four specified ["WGD","PND","OTD","BTD"].

Second click on the checkbox unchecks it and the layer now show only the three object types. ["WGD","PND","OTD"]

With the checkbox checked again I expect the objecttype "BTD" to return but this doesn't happen.

How should this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the filter is more like a delete statement in SQL than a where clause. I got it to work by creating a copy of the original layer and displaying the copy.

```
if (layerFilter) 

{ map.removeLayer(layerFilter); }

layer1.setVisible(true);

layerFilter = layer1.applyFilter(new OM.filter.In('OBJECTTYPE',filterArray),false);

layer1.setVisible(false);

map.addLayer(layerFilter);
```